# Error in measurement

Tags: measurements, error-analysis, length

A part of my question says ***"...measured value of L is 20.0 cm known to 1mm accuracy..."***; in the solution thereafter ***Del L*** is taken as 1 mm. The least count of the metre scale is 1 mm right? So it should be accurate up to 1 mm; the question itself says ***"it can be measured up to 1 mm accuracy"***,  but  the uncertainty is still taken as 1 mm. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Please examine what you mean by "*The least count of the metre scale is 1 mm right?*", i suspect you are barking up the wrong forest, not just the wrong tree here.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, most of the time, and especially when working with "primitive" measurement equipment like rulers and the like, uncertainties on measurements have to be understood as an estimate rather than something absolute. In the lectures on data evaluation I heard, the convention mostly was to use half of the smallest mark distance of the scale as uncertainty and this uncertainty was interpreted as the standard deviation $\sigma$ of a single measurement, meaning that when conducting infinitely many measurements, around 68 % of them would be in the intervall of width $2\sigma$ around any one of the obtained values.

In your case, if using a metre scale with 1mm marks, I would use a standard deviation of the single measurement of 0.5mm, so the width of my interval of uncertainty would be $2 \cdot 0.5\mathrm{mm} = 1\mathrm{mm}$ and getting a result in that interval of $[20.0\mathrm{mm} - 0.5\mathrm{mm},20.0 \mathrm{mm} + 0.5 \mathrm{mm}]$ would be 68% likely when repeating the measurement.

Now since you did not define what exactly you mean by "accuracy", I would interpret it as the width of that uncertainty interval.